# Gather first letter from each string in a list of strings

Tags: beginner, haskell, null

I'm learning Haskell on my own, and I'm wondering if this is idiomatic Haskell.

In particular: is it a common pattern to "wrap" the result in a list in order to make a function total? (that's what I ended up doing to ensure the function was total and no compiler warnings about not matching a pattern).

```
safeHead :: [a] -> Maybe a
safeHead []     = Nothing
safeHead (x:_)  = Just x

firstLetters :: [String] -> [Char]
firstLetters ss = concat $
                     map (\s -> case safeHead s of
                                Nothing -> []
                                Just c  -> [c]) ss
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well a few thoughts, of all `String = [Char]` so we could really give the signature

```
firstLetters :: [String] -> String
```

Whether you think this is better is a matter of taste. Second, you should take a look at

```
Data.Maybe.mapMaybe :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

It's exactly what you'd expect, it applies a function to `Maybe`s and prunes out the `Nothing`s. This simplifies the slightly ugly `concat` bit.

```
 firstLetters = mapMaybe safeHead
```

Much clearer :) In the interest of teaching you to fish, [here's how](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a%20-%3E%20Maybe%20b%29%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D%20-%3E%20%5Bb%5D) I found the name of `mapMaybe`

Comment: When you say "is a matter of taste" is that a 50/50 divide in the Haskell community, or more like a 90/10 towards using String?

Comment: @j-a 50/50. In general you should prefer `String` when you're using well strings. In all other cases it's entirely up to you!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @jozefg's answer, `Data.Maybe` also contains [`listToMaybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:listToMaybe).

> `listToMaybe :: [a] -> Maybe a`
>
> The `listToMaybe` function returns `Nothing` on an empty list or `Just a`
>   where `a` is the first element of the list.

Which reduces the code to

```
firstLetters = mapMaybe listToMaybe
```